# Not able to insert data into hbase table using PIG

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

if i run ->

```
data = LOAD 'hdfs:/user/zzz/Pokemon.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (serial_no:int,name:chararray,type1:chararray,type2:chararray,total:int,hp:int,attack:int,defence:int,sp_attk:int,sp_def:int,speed:int);
```

data loaded successfully as i can see by dumping the data.
but after that when i run ->

```
STORE data INTO 'hbase://pokemons' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf:name,cf:type1,cf:type2,cf:total,cf:hp,cf:attack,cf:defence,cf:sp_attk,cf:sp_def,cf:speed');
```

then the problem arises you can check that below ->

```
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
3.2.1   0.17.0  zzz 2019-12-11 12:57:34 2019-12-11 12:57:43 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1576044193401_0008  data    MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed!    hbase://pokemons,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs:/user/zzz/Pokemon.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hbase://pokemons"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1576044193401_0008


2019-12-11 12:57:43,115 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
```

Comment: Look at the yarn container to see the real error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what happened but I do know that current Pig is not tested against hadoop version 3 or higher.  Tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-5253